# Nine point center in barycentric coordinates

Tags: barycentric-coordinates

Is there a short way to compute the barycentric coordinates of the nine point center:
$N=(a \cos (B-C): b \cos (C-A) : c \cos(B-A) )$ 
When I try I get lost in calculations..

Comment: Looks like there are some cosine functions missing in your formula.